# Version conflict during import SBT project (Play Framework) in IntelliJ IDEA 15.0.2

Tags: intellij-idea, import, playframework, sbt, typesafe

I built application using Typesafe Activator, Play 2.5.0-M1 (activator) in IntelliJ IDEA 15.0.2, and when I import/open it ...

```
SBT project import

[warn] Multiple dependencies with the same organization/name but different versions. To avoid conflict, pick one version: 
[warn] * org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:(4.0.1, 4.3.4) 
[warn] * com.google.guava:guava:(18.0, 16.0.1) 
[warn] * org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:(4.0.1, 4.3.2) 
[warn] * commons-logging:commons-logging:(1.1.1, 1.1.3) 
[warn] * org.scala-lang.modules:scala-parser-combinators_2.11:(1.0.1, 1.0.3) 
[warn] * org.scala-lang.modules:scala-xml_2.11:(1.0.1, 1.0.3)

[SBT project import conflict][1]
```

***What changes should I make to my project or IntelliJ IDEA configuration?***

[link to GitHub repository](https://github.com/jsdevelopcom/WebAddressBook)

Comment: This looks just like a warning and everything should be working. What problem are you seeing?

Comment: @marcospereira I don't run my app yet, I'll push it on GitHub soon and post the link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try dependencyOverrides key to specify exactly which version you want to use. This will turn off the warning.

http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Library-Management.html#Overriding+a+version

Comment: Thanks a lot, but I don't understand how correctly make changes to build.sbt ... :    dependencyOverrides += "org.apache" % "apache" % "4.3.4"

Comment: or: dependencyOverrides += "org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:" % "apache" % "4.3.4"

Comment: Look at the colons in the warning message, org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:(4.0.1, 4.3.4), tells you where the separators should be. So it should be "org.apache.httpcomponents" % "httpclient" % "4.3.4"